# What does 'to be maxed out' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idioms, meaning-in-context

[image]

I want to understand what Chandler means when he says he's maxed out after thinking he's embarrassed by his bunny costume.

Answer (score 2):

He's reached his limit or maximum. He's exhausted and therefore impervious to embarrassment (not the other way around, i.e., he's embarrassed and therefore maxed out).

Comment: What means 'to be maxed out' at all? How and when can I use it?

Comment: If someone is maxed out, he or she is fatigued and exhausted. After a strenuous workout, you can say "I'm maxed out, buddies! Let's get some burgers."

Answer (score 1):

*max out:*

to reach the limit of one's capacity, endurance, etc.

I think the above definition may fit, though more details about the dialogue may help to understand the context.